# Проблема NTLM в GLPI

Tags: apache, ntlm, http

Привет всем. Хочу сделать авто вход в GLPI через AD по средствам NTLM. Но вот не получается. NTLM авторизация, как я понял, работает но некорректно. При входе в GLPI система авторизует, но выскакивает все время окно ввода логина и пароля. Пробовал вводить логин пароль пользователя - не помогает. В чем проблема, не пойму. Искал по тексту ошибок в логах apache2  сервера, но так и не пришел к единому мнению, как решить данную проблему. Пробовал запустить скрипт php, который проверяет NTLM авторизацию, вроде все правильно определяет. Может я что-то не то делаю? Вот этот скрипт:

```
<?php

/***********************************************************************
*    PHP NTLM GET LOGIN
*    Version 0.2
* ====================================================
*
* Copyright (c) 2004 Nicolas GOLLET (Nicolas.gollet@secusquad.com)
* Copyright (c) 2004 Flextronics Saint-Etienne
*
* This program is free software. You can redistribute it and/or modify
* it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
* the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License.
*
***********************************************************************/

/*
L'identification par NTLM se fait en 6 etape :

etape: | type:      | Info echange
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------
    1   | C --> S       | GET ...                               legende : C = Client
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------                     S = Serveur
    2   | C <-- S   | 401 Unauthorized
         |              | WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------
    3   | C --> S       | GET ...
         |              | Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-1-message>
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------
    4   | C <-- S   | 401 Unauthorized
         |              | WWW-Authenticate: NTLM <base64-encoded type-2-message>
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------
    5   | C --> S       | GET ...
         |              | Authorization: NTLM <base64-encoded type-3-message>
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------
    6   | C <-- S        | 200 Ok
-------|----------------|--------------------------------------------------

*/

$headers = apache_request_headers();    // Recuperation des l'entetes client

if($headers['Authorization'] == NULL){              //si l'entete autorisation est inexistante
    header( "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" );          //envoi au client le mode d'identification
    header( "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM" );         //dans notre cas le NTLM
    exit;                           //on quitte

};

if(isset($headers['Authorization']))                //dans le cas d'une authorisation (identification)
{
    if(substr($headers['Authorization'],0,5) == 'NTLM '){   // on verifit que le client soit en NTLM

        $chaine=$headers['Authorization'];
        $chaine=substr($chaine, 5);             // recuperation du base64-encoded type1 message
        $chained64=base64_decode($chaine);      // decodage base64 dans $chained64

        if(ord($chained64{8}) == 1){
        //          |_ byte signifiant l'etape du processus d'identification (etape 3)

        // verification du drapeau NTLM "0xb2" a l'offset 13 dans le message type-1-message :
        if (ord($chained64[13]) != 178){
        echo "Votre navigateur Internet n'est pas compatible avec le NTLM, utiliser IE...Merci";
        exit;
        }
            $retAuth = "NTLMSSP";
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(2);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(40);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(1);
            $retAuth .= chr(130);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(2);
            $retAuth .= chr(2);
            $retAuth .= chr(2);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);
            $retAuth .= chr(0);

            $retAuth64 =base64_encode($retAuth);        // encode en base64
            $retAuth64 = trim($retAuth64);          // enleve les espaces de debut et de fin
            header( "HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" );      // envoi le nouveau header
            header( "WWW-Authenticate: NTLM $retAuth64" );  // avec l'identification supplementaire
            exit;

        }

        else if(ord($chained64{8}) == 3){
        //               |_ byte signifiant l'etape du processus d'identification (etape 5)

        // on recupere le domaine

        $lenght_domain = (ord($chained64[31])*256 + ord($chained64[30])); // longueur du domain
        $offset_domain = (ord($chained64[33])*256 + ord($chained64[32])); // position du domain.
        $domain = substr($chained64, $offset_domain, $lenght_domain); // decoupage du du domain

        //le login
        $lenght_login = (ord($chained64[39])*256 + ord($chained64[38])); // longueur du login.
        $offset_login = (ord($chained64[41])*256 + ord($chained64[40])); // position du login.
        $login = substr($chained64, $offset_login, $lenght_login); // decoupage du login

        // l'host
        $lenght_host = (ord($chained64[47])*256 + ord($chained64[46])); // longueur de l'host.
        $offset_host = (ord($chained64[49])*256 + ord($chained64[48])); // position de l'host.
        $host = substr($chained64, $offset_host, $lenght_host); // decoupage du l'host

        echo "Domain is  : $domain";
        echo "<br>Login is : $login";
        echo "<br>host is  : $host";

        }

    }

}

?>
```

Скрипт показывает логин, имя машины и домен.
 Конфигурация такая:

```
<Directory "/var/www/glpi/">
        AuthName NTAuth
        AuthType NTLM
        NTLMAuth on
        NTLMAuthoritative on
        NTLMDomain garant-servis.ru
        NTLMServer srv
        NTLMBackup srv
        require valid-user
        Satisfy all
        Allow from all
        NTLMLockfile /tmp/ntlmauth.lck
</Directory>
```

Сообщение об ошибке Apache2:

```
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/script.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/script.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/lib/extjs/ext-all.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extjs/ext-all.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1390 /glpi/lib/extrajs/xdatefield.js - send_ntlm_challenge: no conn. handle...trouble communicating with PDC/BDC? returning internal server error, referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:40 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/lib/extrajs/datetime.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/datetime.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/pics/fd_nav1.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_nav1.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/pics/ok2.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/ok2.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/pics/fd_ssmenu.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_ssmenu.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/pics/fd_hoverlink.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_hoverlink.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/pics/fd_nav3.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_nav3.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/pics/bookmark.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/bookmark.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/pics/fd_footer.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_footer.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/pics/fd_logo.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_logo.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] 2000 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:44 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2000 /glpi/pics/fd_nav2.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_nav2.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:53 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/css/styles.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/css/styles.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/css/styles.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/css/styles.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/css/print.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/css/print.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/lib/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/css/ext-all-glpi.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/css/ext-all-glpi.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/lib/extjs/locale/ext-lang-ru.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extjs/locale/ext-lang-ru.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 2000 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2000 /glpi/lib/extrajs/xdatefield.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/xdatefield.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/lib/extrajs/spancombobox.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/spancombobox.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/lib/extrajs/datetime.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/datetime.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/starslider/slider.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/lib/extjs/ext-all.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extjs/ext-all.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/css/tab-scroller-menu.css - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/css/tab-scroller-menu.css", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 2000 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2000 /glpi/lib/extrajs/TabScrollerMenu.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extrajs/TabScrollerMenu.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:54 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/script.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/script.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:55 2012] [error] 2173 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:55 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2173 /glpi/lib/extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/lib/extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] 1389 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1389 /glpi/pics/ok2.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/ok2.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] 1999 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1999 /glpi/pics/bookmark.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/bookmark.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] 2173 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:33:58 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2173 /glpi/pics/menu_all.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/menu_all.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:03 2012] [error] 2000 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:03 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2000 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:07 2012] [error] 1386 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:07 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1386 /glpi/test1.php - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/test1.php"
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:10 2012] [error] 2173 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:10 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2173 /glpi/test1.php - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/test1.php"
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:11 2012] [error] 2040 - SMB_Logon_Server: Error sending SessSetupX request
[Wed Aug 08 17:34:11 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 2040 /glpi/test1.php - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/test1.php"
[Wed Aug 08 17:35:09 2012] [error] 1388 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:35:09 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1388 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
[Wed Aug 08 17:37:53 2012] [error] 1387 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:37:53 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.233] 578157960 1387 /glpi/pics/fd_footer.png - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/pics/fd_footer.png", referer: http://192.168.0.73/glpi/front/central.php
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:46 2012] [error] 1390 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:46 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1390 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:49 2012] [error] 1390 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:49 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1390 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:50 2012] [error] 1390 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:50 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1390 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:50 2012] [error] 1390 - SMB_Logon_Server: SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5\n
[Wed Aug 08 17:38:50 2012] [error] [client 192.168.0.231] 578157960 1390 /glpi/ - NTLM/SMB user "(null)": authentication failure for "/glpi/"
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux ocsinventory-ng 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:13:04 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Настраивал с помощью http://www.z4blog.ru/2011/10/prozrachnaya-avtorizaciya-v-glpi/

и http://www.glpi-project.org/wiki/doku.php?id=en:authautoad

Answer (score 1):

проблему с SMB_Logon_Server:

> SMB_SessSetupAndX failed; errorclass = 1, Error Code = 5

похоже, никто не исследовал.
А она, оказывается, связана с тем, что в mod_`ntlm.c:ntlm_check_response()` (строчка примерно 600) есть проверка (т.е. пользователь уже аутентифицирован и к серверу больше обращаться не нужно):

```
if (ntlm_connection->auth_ok && ntlm_connection->user) {
/* user has already valid credentials */
if ((!strcmp(ntlm_connection->user, ntlmssp->user))
&& (!strcmp(ntlm_connection->domain, ntlmssp->domain))
&& (!memcmp(ntlm_connection->password, ntlmssp->nt, RESP_LEN))) {
log(r, APLOG_INFO, “silent reauthentication”);
/* silently accept login with same credentials */
r->user = apr_pstrdup(r->connection->pool, ntlm_connection->user);
r->ap_auth_type = apr_pstrdup(r->connection->pool, NTLM_AUTH_NAME);
return OK;
}
```

В `(!memcmp(ntlm_connection->password, ntlmssp->nt, RESP_LEN))` `password` и `nt` содержат разные значения. Как workaround я закомментировал эту проверку на совпадение пароля. После этого все стало хорошо.

М.б. кто-нибудь посмотрит, почему портится password. Мне что-то лениво, т.к. от NTLM нужно только имя пользователя, который заходит на сайт, а авторизация делается локальными средствами :) .